What the minimum length of Internationalized TLDs?
An usual top-level domain (TLD) has a minimum length of 2 characters. Is this rule applies to   Internationalized TLDs too (like  .中国 .مصر .भारत)?
I'm writing a Regex to validate email.

This isn't obviously a programming question, but it isn't obviously not one either… If you're writing code to detect links in running text or similar, you might want to edit the question and mention that explicitly. It'll help people who search for this aspect of the same task.

Yes, it applies, two letters is the minimum for IDNs as well. It may however be relaxed in the next year or two, single-character IDN TLDs have been proposed for Chinese. I don't think any decision has been made.

as I know there is no 2 letters limitation in any RFC, so there is a IANA or ICANN rule?

It's an ICANN rule.
